# URL routing in codeigniter is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I need to send a var (an int with value 3) to an index function in a controller.
No problems with that, except the url looks like this:

```
tasks/index/3
```

I want the url to be like this:

```
tasks/
```

I tried this in the routes.php, but then it gives an error saying the page can't be found.

```
$route['tasks/index/(:num)'] = 'tasks';
```

Comment: what page doesn't work ? what's the url?

Comment: are you sure your tasks controller have the index method? Please provide more code so we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the other way around.

Try doing:

```
$route['tasks/(:num)'] = 'tasks/index/$1';
```

[CI Routing docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Yes, it works now. Looks like I indeed worked the other way around. xD Thanks